# Sort array using values from separate hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array of IDs and a separate hash that dictates how those IDs should be ordered.  Something like this:

Array:

```
[
  7,
  3,
  2,
]
```

Sort ranks:

```
{
  1 => 50,
  2 => 70,
  3 => 10,
  4 => 80,
  5 => 60,
  6 => 20,
  7 => 0,
}
```

I want to elegantly reverse sort the first array by using the values of the hash.  So the result should be this:

```
[
    2,
    3,
    7,
]
```

I know there are brute force methods, but is there an easier and more performant way to do this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The kid wants to sort an array of objects based on a weight represented in a hash for a certain property on those objects.

Comment: I updated it with an actual question and, hopefully, to simplify the question slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have `order_hash` and `object_array` defined, you can sort using following code:

```
object_array.sort{ |a, b| order_hash[b[:id]] <=> order_hash[a[:id]] }
```

you can use some constant for instead of `order_hash` if you want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the <=> operator.  What does that do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about more performant but here's a relatively simple way

```
arr = [
  {
    :id => 7,
  },
  {
    :id => 3,
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
  }
]

ranks = {
  1 => 50,
  2 => 70,
  3 => 10,
  4 => 80,
  5 => 60,
  6 => 20,
  7 => 0,
}

arr2 = arr.sort_by{|elem| -ranks[elem[:id]]}

arr2 # => [{:id=>2}, {:id=>3}, {:id=>7}]
```

Comment: Given that they're numbers, why not `-ranks[elem[:id]]` instead of the `.reverse`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
input = [
  7,
  3,
  2,
]

ranks = {
  1 => 50,
  2 => 70,
  3 => 10,
  4 => 80,
  5 => 60,
  6 => 20,
  7 => 0,
}

result = input.sort_by{|x| ranks[x]} #=> [7, 3, 2]
```